# What are the cognitive capabilities of azure search while searching?

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I know azure search has various cognitive skills like image analysis, OCR, etc .But these skills are used during indexing.
I want to know is there any feature used by azure search during the search that can be termed as cognitive capability?

Answer (score 0):

During the search process, Sematic Search can be considered as it uses Natural Language Understanding to fix mispelled words and also provide relevant results for your searched term.

e.g. ('what is the capital of France?') it won't try to find each word in the inverted index, but to find answer to provided query

Comment: Thiago is correct.  [Semantic search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/semantic-search-overview#how-semantic-ranking-works) uses AI models at query time to perform cognitive tasks such as Q&A, semantic highlighting, and intent based ranking of results.